# symfony The function "form" does not exist

Tags: forms, symfony

I am new in symfony2, I wanted to create a simple form and here is my code :
in the controller :

```
    public function testAction(Request $request) {    
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
    ->add('name','text')
    ->add('age','integer')
    ->add('save','submit')
    ->getForm()
    ;//initializing the form
     return $this->render('LoginLoginBundle:Default:test.html.twig', array     ('myform'=>$form->createView()));
}  
}
```

in the twig file:

```
{%extends "::base.html.twig"%}
{% block body %}
{{ form(myform)}} 
{% endblock %}
```

I get this error :
    Could not load type "submit"
and even if I delete  ->add('save','submit') I get this error :

```
The function "form" does not exist. Did you mean "form_row", "form_rest", "form_label", "form_errors", "form_widget", "form_enctype" in LoginLoginBundle:Default:test.html.twig at line 3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have Symfony 2.2 you should update it to 2.5.
But if you want to keep your version, you must read this [doc](http://symfony.com/doc/2.2/book/forms.html). They tell you you need to render your form with this code :

```
{% extends "::base.html.twig"%}
{% block body %}
    <form action="{{ path('your_route') }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(myform) }}>
        {{ form_widget(myform) }}

        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

(You can see that the "submit" button must be rendered in the template and that you can't add it in your controller with your version of Symfony)

Comment: thx, it works,I don't want to update because I will have trouble in dependencies with other vendors. but please edit 'form' to 'myform' to show that this is the passed variable. :)