# The function "form" does not exist

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have a view which render a controller:
`{{ render(controller("AsselinVisaBundle:Visa:ajouter")) }}`
This controller build a form and render another view where I render the form.

Here my controller:

```
public function ajouterAction() {
        $visa = new Visa();
        $form = $this->createForm(new VisaType(), $visa);

        return $this->render(
            "AsselinVisaBundle:Visa:ajout.html.twig",
            array("form" => $form->createView())
        );
    }
```

In the view ajout.html.twig, I only have:
`{{ form(form) }}`

Here my Visa entity:

```
   <?php

    namespace Asselin\VisaBundle\Entity;

    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

    /**
     * @ORM\Entity
     * @ORM\Table(name="visa")
     */
    class Visa {

        /**
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\Column(type="string")
         */
        private $numero;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="string")
         */
        private $salarie;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="string")
         */
        private $pays;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="date")
         */
        private $delivrance;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="date")
         */
        private $expiration;


        /**
         * Set numero
         *
         * @param string $numero
         * @return Visa
         */
        public function setNumero($numero)
        {
            $this->numero = $numero;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get numero
         *
         * @return string 
         */
        public function getNumero()
        {
            return $this->numero;
        }

        /**
         * Set salarie
         *
         * @param string $salarie
         * @return Visa
         */
        public function setSalarie($salarie)
        {
            $this->salarie = $salarie;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get salarie
         *
         * @return string 
         */
        public function getSalarie()
        {
            return $this->salarie;
        }

        /**
         * Set pays
         *
         * @param string $pays
         * @return Visa
         */
        public function setPays($pays)
        {
            $this->pays = $pays;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get pays
         *
         * @return string 
         */
        public function getPays()
        {
            return $this->pays;
        }

        /**
         * Set delivrance
         *
         * @param \DateTime $delivrance
         * @return Visa
         */
        public function setDelivrance($delivrance)
        {
            $this->delivrance = $delivrance;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get delivrance
         *
         * @return \DateTime 
         */
        public function getDelivrance()
        {
            return $this->delivrance;
        }

        /**
         * Set expiration
         *
         * @param \DateTime $expiration
         * @return Visa
         */
        public function setExpiration($expiration)
        {
            $this->expiration = $expiration;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get expiration
         *
         * @return \DateTime 
         */
        public function getExpiration()
        {
            return $this->expiration;
        }
    }
```

And here my VisaType:

```
<?php

namespace Asselin\VisaBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class VisaType extends AbstractType {

    public function buidForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder) {
        $builder->add("numero", "text");
        $builder->add("salarie", "text");
        $builder->add("pays", "text");
        $builder->add("delivrance", "date");
        $builder->add("expiration", "date");
    }

    public function getName() { return "visa"; }

}

?>
```

I have an exception:

> The function " form" does not exist. Did you mean "form" in...

The error is here: `{{ form(form) }}`

Do you have an idea?

Thanks :)

Comment: An idea of what?  Is there a problem or issue?  If so state it in the question

Comment: Please don't paste your entire code. Just the portion related to your problem.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf I have an exception "The function 'form' does not exist" at the line "{{ form(form) }}"

Comment: Then you should edit your question to include that detail.

Comment: Try form_widget(form)

Comment: @mr12086 same problem "The function 'form_widget' does not exist". Is it not because I render the controller in a template ?

Comment: Is this a standard Symfony framework project?

Comment: @Gerry Yes this is Symfony Framework Standard edition

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24150411/symfony-the-function-form-does-not-exist

Comment: @Patt I already seen this post and it didn't help me

Comment: What version are you using ?

Comment: @TomToms Symfony 2.6

Comment: I use silex framework - so dont setup using yaml, but is twigbundle setup correctly? http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/twig.html

Comment: Well that's weird unless you managed to disable the FormExtension you shouldn't receive that message. Can you post your config.yml ? (twig: & services: relevant to twig)

Comment: @mr12086 I never changed any configuration file (just routing file)

Comment: Do post what you have there anyway it is more relevant than the controller/entity/type code for the problem. How about twig's vendor, did you modify them ? Might be worth trying to reinstall them anyways.

Comment: try using `vardump()` to see if form is available on twig or not

Comment: remove the white space : {{ form(form) }} => {{form(form)}}   ---- The error message says it doesn't know ' form'

Comment: @YenneInfo It's work! What the hell is that?

Comment: Don't know, I'd the same problem last year, stupid resolution, but it works, i post it as an answer....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The problem :**
The error message says it doesn't know `' form'`

**The resolution :**
*remove the white space :*

`{{ form(form) }}` become  `{{form(form)}}`

Comment: I will post this bug (I think it's a bug) to Symfony devel.
Thanks!